# how many night/nights accommodations?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am trying to construct following sentence:

> Depending on how many **nights** accommodations that company would like to provide.

I have two questions:

1. does this sentence make sense? do you understand what I am trying to say?
2. should I use *night* accommodations or *nights* accommodations?

Comment: encoder beat me to an answer, but note that your example is not a complete sentence.  "depending on" introduces a condition that defines something else.  The rest of your example is the condition.  But then it's missing what it is that the condition affects.

Comment: Plural sounds weird. In these cases the noun acts like an adjective, e.g. "four-night accommodation", but I don't know if it could work with how many. I can see it working, "how-many-night accommodation", but I don't know if it's correct. I'd go with something like "depending on the length of the accommodation".

Comment: I disagree with Korvin; *night* is not acting as a noun adjunct here, so the plural is absolutely correct, because it's an *accommodation of four nights*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicate that there may be a number of nights, then nights is the correct form.  If they decided to only provide one night, that would be said, one night's accommodation (the accommodation of one night).